# on etherscan Why input Data amount value and ERC-20 tokens Transferred value are different

Tags: transactions, erc-20, tokens

In this case
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9412e437f29fa5719de54c5374f0a89fbe78786060db05b2cb9a5ffb189e04d8
Why **input Data amount** value and **ERC-20 tokens Transferred** value are different?

Answer (score 0):

Value is always the amount of **ETH transferred** within the transaction, whereas the amount is defined within the function call parameters (inputs).

To understand why that is, you should look into smart contracts and you will find that ERC20 balances are just values saved within a contract, whereas ETH is a native currency, so it's being sent at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "Reflect contract". The amounts aren't fixed, but uses a mechanism to autoadjust its value. See here for more detail [Binance Smart Chain tokens: What are tTotal, rTotal, tSupply, rSupply, rOwned, tOwned which I see everywhere?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98622/binance-smart-chain-tokens-what-are-ttotal-rtotal-tsupply-rsupply-rowned-t).